# Mysql view and group

Tags: mysql, sql, view, group-by

I have a table with the following structure:

```
id (int),
stock_class(varchar(10)),
stock_number(varchar(10)),
Store_1 (varchar(1)) - the values here can be Y or N, indicating ability to keep this stock_number at Store_1
Store_2 (varchar(1)) -
```

the values here can be Y or N, indicating ability to keep this stock_number at Store_1

The data in the table looks like this (comma delimited):

1,a,aa,y, n

2,a,ab,n,n

3,a,ac,y,y

4,b,ba,y,y

5,b,bb,n,n

6,b,bc,n,y

and so on...

I would like to create a view that shows the data grouped by stock_class, but show the stock types which have "y" per store.

Something like this (comma delimited):
stock_class,stock_number_y_Store_1,stock_number_y_Store_2

a, aa/ac,ac

b,ba,ba/bc

Can you please help?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select stock_class, 
group_concat(case store_1 when 'y' then stock_number end separator '/') as stock_number_y_Store_1,
group_concat(case store_2 when 'y' then stock_number end separator '/') as stock_number_y_Store_2
from NoOneNamesTheirTableInSqlQuestions
group by stock_class
```

Demo: [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bfbc6/3)

Answer (score 0):

Why not just :

`SELECT stock_class FROM table WHERE Store_1 = 'Y' GROUP BY stock_class`

?

If you want to get all records use ORDER instead of GROUP…